# Why does Map<K,V> not extends Function<K,V>?

Tags: java-8

While playing around with the new Java 8 `Stream` API I got to wondering, why not:

```
public interface Map<K,V> extends Function<K, V>
```

Or even:

```
public interface Map<K,V> extends Function<K, V>, Predicate<K>
```

It would be fairly easy to implement with `default` methods on the `Map` `interface`:

```
@Override default boolean test(K k) {
    return containsKey(k);
}

@Override default V apply(K k) {
    return get(k);
}
```

And it would allow for the use of a `Map` in a `map` method:

```
final MyMagicMap<String, Integer> map = new MyMagicHashMap<>();
map.put("A", 1);
map.put("B", 2);
map.put("C", 3);
map.put("D", 4);

final Stream<String> strings = Arrays.stream(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"});
final Stream<Integer> remapped = strings.map(map);
```

Or as a `Predicate` in a `filter` method.

I find that a significant proportion of my use cases for a `Map` are exactly that construct or a similar one - as a remapping/lookup `Function`.

So, why did the JDK designers not decide to add this functionality to the `Map` during the redesign for Java 8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JDK team was certainly aware of the mathematical relationship between `java.util.Map` as a data structure and `java.util.function.Function` as a mapping function. After all, `Function` was named `Mapper` in early JDK 8 [prototype builds](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-August/003797.html). And the stream operation that calls a function on each stream element is called `Stream.map`.

There was even a discussion about possibly renaming `Stream.map` to something else like `transform` because of possible confusion between a transforming function and a `Map` data structure. (Sorry, can't find a link.) This proposal was rejected, with the rationale being the conceptual similarity (and that `map` for this purpose is in common usage).

The main question is, what would be gained if `java.util.Map` were a subtype of `java.util.function.Function`? There was some discussion in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388560/why-does-mapk-v-not-extends-functionk-v#comment46955664_29388651) about whether subtyping implies an "is-a" relationship. Subtyping is less about "is-a" relationships of objects -- since we're talking about interfaces, not classes -- but it does imply *substitutability*. So if `Map` were a subtype of `Function`, one would be able to do this:

```
Map<K,V> m = ... ;
source.stream().map(m).collect(...);
```

Right away we're confronted with baking in the behavior of what is now `Function.apply` to one of the existing `Map` methods. Probably the only sensible one is `Map.get`, which returns null if the key isn't present. These semantics are, frankly, kind of lousy. Real applications are probably going to have to write their own methods that supply key-missing policy anyway, so there seems to be very little advantage of being able to write

```
map(m)
```

instead of

```
map(m::get)
```

or

```
map(x -> m.getOrDefault(x, def))
```

Comment: I think the point about baking in `map::get` rather than `getOrDefault` or `computeIfAbsent` or whatever else if the most compelling argument so far. I can see that `null` would be an issue, especially being as many a `Stream` would start life as `NONNULL`. Thank you for your valuable insight into the design decision!

Answer (score 8):

The question is “why should it extend `Function`?”

Your example of using `strings.map(map)` doesn’t really justify the idea of changing the type inheritance (implying adding methods to the `Map` interface), given the little difference to `strings.map(map::get)`. And it’s not clear whether using a `Map` as a `Function` is really that common that it should get that special treatment compared to, e.g. using `map::remove` as a `Function` or using `map::get` of a `Map<…,Integer>` as `ToIntFunction` or `map::get` of a `Map<T,T>` as `BinaryOperator`.

That’s even more questionable in the case of a `Predicate`; should `map::containsKey` really get a special treatment compared to `map::containsValue`?

It’s also worth noting the type signature of the methods. `Map.get` has a functional signature of `Object → V` while you suggests that `Map<K,V>` should extend `Function<K,V>` which is understandable from a conceptional view of maps (or just by looking at the type), but it shows that there are two conflicting expectations, depending on whether you look at the method or at the type. The best solution is not to fix the functional type. Then you can assign `map::get` to either `Function<Object,V>` or `Function<K,V>` and everyone is happy…

Comment: I think this is a much better argument than [JB Nizet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29388651/2071828), I can see the logic here. The key point seems to be that having `Map<K,V> extends Function<K,V>` would cause issues with Java primitives (`ToXXXFunction`) and, more importantly, wouldn't play nicely with the (somewhat hacky) signature of `get` - are those the main considerations? The basic answer in that case seems to be "legacy issues"...

Comment: @Boris the Spider: I can’t look into the developers mind. Maybe they actually never thought about it at all. Especially as there is no attempt to retrofit existing types to functions at all, e.g. letting `Comparator` extend `ToIntBiFunction` etc. Maybe the simpler answer is that functions and other types are considered generally distinct. Having `Map` extending `Function` implies that you could create such gems as calling `firstMap.compose(otherMap)`…

Comment: Blaming it on "legacy" issues is too easy.  Holger has it right; the right question is "why should it", rather than "why didn't it."  And there was no compelling reason why it should, especially given how simple it is to convert map::get or list::contains to Function or Predicate.

Comment: @BrianGoetz thank you for your comment, I think [Stuart Marks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29395264/2071828) raises the most compelling reason however, with the ambiguity in the behaviour of a `Map` as a `Function`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think Brian and I are basically saying the same thing, except I wrote more words. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Because a Map is not a Function. Inheritance is for *A is a B* relationships. Not for *A can be the subject of various kinds of B* relationships.

To have a function transforming a key to its value, you just need

```
Function<K, V> f = map::get;
```

To have a predicate testing if an object is contained in a map, you just need

```
Predicate<Object> p = map::contains;
```

That is both clearer and more readable than your proposal.

Comment: Poking around in Scala shows that their [`Map` does mixin a `PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.MapLike). I suppose that's just a different design decision, but it shows that maybe it's not quite as clear cut as all that...

Comment: How a map is not a function? I think it's perfectly fine to define a Map as a function such that `f(k) = v` on the domain defined by the keys in the map and `f(x) = null` if x is not in the domain.

Comment: @user2336315  A map is not a function in a mathematical sense. Multiple calls with the same key can yield different results.

Comment: I would also disagree with the assessment that `implementing` an `interface` implies an _is a_ relationship...

Comment: @user2336315 `Map<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<>(); users.get(10); users.put(10, newUser); user.get(10);` Not the same result -> not a function.

Comment: @zeroflagL But then we can consider that it's a new function with a new image set. At a time t, it really behaves like a function: